# Is this a Hilbert space? If not, is it reflexive?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $L^2(\Omega, E)$ denote the space of random variables taking values in $E$ with second order moment. Is $L^2(\Omega,E)$ a Hilbert space? or at least, reflexive?

1) I do not see if it is a Hilbert space, because I do not manage to find a suitable inner product... My guess is $E[XY]$, $X,Y\in L^2(\Omega,E)$ but then the product is not defined. Of course if $E=H$ Hilbert then $E[<X,Y>_H]$ is an inner product in $L^2(\Omega,H)$.

2) I do not know how to check if it is reflexive.

Any help would be highly appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Note: If $\Omega$ has a subset of measure $1$, you have an isometric embedding $E \hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega,E)$. If $\Omega$ has a subset of measure $0 < c < +\infty$, then you have an almost-isometric embedding (norms are multiplied with $\sqrt{c}$). What does that tell you about _necessary_ conditions on $E$ for the space to be a Hilbert space or reflexive?

Comment: $\Omega$ has measure 1 w.r.t. $P$ right? So $\Omega$ is already a subset of measure 1 right? What do you mean by a subset of $\Omega$ with also measure 1? I guess $E$ has to be reflexive too then?

Comment: Ah, you're assuming a probability measure of course. I thought of the more general setting. Yes, since $E$ is (isometrically isomorphic to) a subspace of $L^2(\Omega,E)$, $E$ needs to be a Hilbert space resp. reflexive itself. Now try to show that these conditions are sufficient.

Comment: When you said it I remembered this, that any Hilbert space can be isometrically embedded into $L^2(\Omega,H)$. I guess the condition that $E$ has to be Hilbert for $L^2(\Omega,E)$ to be Hilbert is both suff. and nec. and for reflexivity... I don't see it directly...

Comment: Have you an idea what space would make an excellent candidate for the dual of $L^2(\Omega,E)$?

Comment: I guess $E^\ast$?. At least we know $L^2(\Omega,E)^\ast \subseteq E^\ast$ right?

Comment: No, that's not right. Think of $E = \mathbb{C}$ for a start.

Comment: mmm... $L^2(\Omega, E^\ast)$? :P